# exit by status 10, - what is this error code stands for?

Tags: iphone, status

I am building an iphone application. I'm able to run this application in iphone simulator.
BUT while installing it into device it is displaying the status code like "TestApp exit with status code -10"

What is meant by this ?
And how to rectify this...