# shishir has exited with status 10?

Tags: iphone

My application is terminating automatically and xcode showing this

> shishir has exited with status 10

What does this mean? I am simply parsing few images, nothing more than that.

regards
shishir

Comment: possible duplicate of [exit by status 10, - what is this error code stands for ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757654/exit-by-status-10-what-is-this-error-code-stands-for)

Answer (score 1):

This means that you application is somehow exiting abnormally.

Try running the application in the debugger and try to pinpoint the line of code causing this exit.